# How to order citations by appearance using BibTeX?

Tags: latex, bibtex

By default (using the `plain` style) BibTeX orders citations alphabetically.

How to order the citations by order of appearance in the document?

Comment: Helpful question (upvoted), but shouldn't this belong to http://tex.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @ChthonicProject, I don't think tex.stackexchange.com started until 2010 and this question is from 2008. Also, the question would be too old to migrate, so it lives on here.

Comment: Delete the .aux and .bbl files and rebuild

Comment: @EmadAghayi Does not work for me.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with \documentclass[acmlarge]{acmart}

Answer (score 306, accepted):

There are three good answers to this question.

- Use the `unsrt` bibliography style, if you're happy with its formatting otherwise
- Use the `makebst` [(link)](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) tool to design your own bibliography style

And my personal recommendation:

- Use the `biblatex` package [(link)](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). It's the most complete and flexible bibliography tool in the LaTeX world.

Using `biblatex`, you'd write something like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{journals,phd-references} % Where journals.bib and phd-references.bib are BibTeX databases
\begin{document}
\cite{robertson2007}
\cite{earnshaw1842}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: One apparent advantage of the biblatex package that caused me to accept this answer is that it allows editing up reference styles using TeX macros rather than weird BibTeX voodoo. Other packages may be better for a quicker/more reliable solution.

Comment: I need to add that if you are using biblatex. It would be better use \addbibresource instead \bibliography. So `\addbibresource{journals.bib,phd-references.bib}`

Comment: I had to use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex, sorting=none]{biblatex}`, otherwise the references would not show up.

Comment: In my case, using `splncs03_unsrt.bst` solved it.

Answer (score 198):

Change

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

to

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

Then rebuild it a few times to replace the `.aux` and `.bbl` files that were made when you used the plain style.

Or simply delete the `.aux` and `.bbl` files and rebuild.

If you use MiKTeX you shouldn't need to download anything extra.

Comment: if you are writing a paper for ACM Publication then `unsrt` would be better than `ieeetr` since the latter is meant for IEEE paper which has a slightly different formatting. `unsrt` and `abbrv` produces the same type of formatting. You might want to take a look at this [link](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~surajit/present/bib.htm)

Comment: **The simple answer arises!** While [Will Robertson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4161/will-robertson)'s `biblatex`-centric [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145207/2809027) is ultimately the way forward for the LaTeX community, LyX's continued lack of built-in support for `biblatex` is an enormous (and increasingly embarrassing) blocker. It's been eight years since this question was first posed! I'll never grok LyX's developer priorities. It's 2016. Driverless cars and portable supercomputers are a thing, yet here we remain – chained to the same execrable BibTeX stone of shame.

Comment: Deleting *.aux* and *.bbl* files fixed my problem.

Comment: It doesn't work in the Overleaf application. I removed them in Overleaf by https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: using biblatex changing the style from numeric to ieee solved my issue

Comment: Worked like a charm (using Overleaf), thank you!

Answer (score 25):

The best I came up with is using the `unsrt` style, which seems to be a tweaked `plain` style. i.e.

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

However what if my style is not the default?

Comment: If you're using a custom BibTeX style, can you edit it to remove the SORT command?

Comment: By default, the wiki page recommends you plain. If you copy-paste carelessly, you'll be using plain instead of unsrt style. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

Comment: If this doesn't work, try deleting the .bbl files, then rerun the latex compilation

Answer (score 24):

Just a brief note - I'm using a modified version of [plain.bst](http://gallium.inria.fr/~remy/latex/plain.bst) sitting in the directory with my Latex files; it turns out having sorting by order of appearance is a relatively easy change; just find the piece of code:

```
...
ITERATE {presort}

SORT
...
```

... and comment it - I turned it to:

```
...
%% % avoid sort:
%% ITERATE {presort}
%%
%% SORT
...
```

... and then, after running `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex` - the citations will be sorted by order of appearance (that is, they will be unsorted :) ).

Cheers!

EDIT: just realized that what I wrote is actually in the comment by @ChrisN: "*can you edit it to remove the SORT command*" ;)

Answer (score 14):

You answered your own question---`unsrt` is to be used when you want references to ne listed in the order of appeareance.

But you might also want to have a look at [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/natbib.html), an extremely flexible citation package. I can not imagine living without it.

Comment: natbib only affects the typesetting of the \cite commands in the document itself. Having said that, it is distributed with unsrtnat.bst to achieve the effect sought by the original poster. (I'd recommend biblatex these days over natbib, unless absolute stability is most important.)

Answer (score 6):

I'm a bit new to Bibtex (and to Latex in general) and I'd like to revive this old post since I found it came up in many of my Google search inquiries about the ordering of a bibliography in Latex.

I'm providing a more verbose answer to this question in the hope that it might help some novices out there facing the same difficulties as me.

Here is an example of the main .tex file in which the bibliography is called:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

So basically this is where the body of your document goes.

``FreeBSD is easy to install,'' said no one ever \cite{drugtrafficker88}.

``Yeah well at least I've got chicken,'' said Leeroy Jenkins \cite{goodenough04}.

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} % Use ieeetr to list refs in the order they're cited
\bibliography{references} % Or whatever your .bib file is called
\end{document}
```

...and an example of the .bib file itself:

```
@ARTICLE{ goodenough04,
AUTHOR    = "G. D. Goodenough and others", 
TITLE     = "What it's like to have a sick-nasty last name",
JOURNAL   = "IEEE Trans. Geosci. Rem. Sens.",
YEAR      = "xxxx",
volume    = "xx",
number    = "xx",
pages     = "xx--xx"
}
@BOOK{ drugtrafficker88,
AUTHOR    = "G. Drugtrafficker", 
TITLE     = "What it's Like to Have a Misleading Last Name",
YEAR      = "xxxx",
PUBLISHER = "Harcourt Brace Jovanovich, Inc."
ADDRESS   = "The Florida Alps, FL, USA"
}
```

Note the references in the .bib file are listed in reverse order but the references are listed in the order they are cited in the paper.

More information on the formatting of your .bib file can be found here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

Answer (score 3):

I often use the bibliography style `natbib` because it supplies quite complete set of formats as well as tags for us.

Answer (score 3):

Add this if you want the number of citations to appear in order in the document
they will only be unsorted in the reference page:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the following in overleaf and become in ascending order:

`\usepackage{cite}`

`\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`

Answer (score 2):

with `unsrt` the problem is the format. use `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` to get refences in order of citation in document.

Comment: Your claim about the format seems to contradict the accepted (and heavily upvoted) answer. Could you clarify?

Comment: ieeetr doesn't seem to order in the order at which they appear.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using `amsrefs` they will override all the above - so comment out:

`\usepackage{amsrefs}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer doesn't appear to actually answer the question posed. Your information could be valuable, but it is probably better suited as comment to one of the other answers (once you have obtained the necessary reputation to post comments).

Answer (score 0):

The [datatool](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package offers a nice way to sort bibliography by an arbitrary criterion, by converting it first into some database format.

Short example, taken [from here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=20461) and posted for the record:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{databib}

\begin{document}
% First argument is the name of new datatool database
% Second argument is list of .bib files
\DTLloadbbl{mybibdata}{acmtr}
% Sort database in order of year starting from most recent
\DTLsort{Year=descending}{mybibdata}
% Add citations
\nocite{*}

% Display bibliography
\DTLbibliography{mybibdata}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `natbib` in combination with `bibliographystyle{apa}`. Eg:

```
\begin{document}

The body of the document goes here...

\newpage

\bibliography{bibliography} % Or whatever you decided to call your .bib file 

\usepackage[round, comma, sort&compress ]{natbib} 

bibliographystyle{apa}
\end{document}
```