# Order of appearance of references in latex

Tags: latex

I am using `revtex`, `\documentclass[onecolumn]{revtex4}`

I would like to have references numbers in order of their appearance but it cannot be performed with `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`

I am writing the references inside the `LaTex` file manually not in a `bibfile`. The references in the main latex work are like

```
\bibitem{stab} Y. S. Myung, Phys. Lett. B 652, 223 (2007).
\bibitem{RevH} S. Wang, Y. Wang, M. Li, Phys. Rep. 696, 1 (2017).
\bibitem{Tavayef} M. Tavayef, A. Sheykhi, K. Bamba, H. Moradpour, Phys. Lett. B 781, 195 (2018).
```

but I have the problem that the numbers of references are nor in order of appearance. Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the reference numbers is always the same as the order of the `\bibitem`s, so in your case `\cite{stab}` will inevitably produce [1].

The `{unsrt}` bibliography style is one which generates its `.bbl` output without sorting the entries in any way, and thus preserving the order in which `\cite` commands were encountered in the main `.tex` file.  That is, the generated `\bibitem` commands in the `.bbl` will end up appearing in citation order.

It's not clear what you mean by ‘it cannot be performed with `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`’.  It should be that if you include `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` in the `.tex` file, and combine that with a suitable `.bib` file, then `bibtex` will generate the `.bbl` file that it appears you're looking for.

If it's a different reference style you're looking for, then you need to select another one which also is unsorted.

Comment: I mean instead of using the `bibfile` I explicitly write the references by hand inside the tex file as I showed above. Now when I use `unsrt` nothing happen to show the numbers of references by appearance order. For example my first numbers of references still is `50` next one is `74` and so on.

Comment: The `\bibliographystyle` command is _purely_ an instruction to BibTeX, and will have no effect if you don't use BibTeX.  If you're inserting `\bibitem` commands in the LaTeX file by hand, then the `\bibliographystyle` command will be ignored.  Can you add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (also, this question might be better on [the TeX Stackexchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com) – I'll possibly migrate it if we don't converge shortly.

Comment: Also, does [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144639/how-to-order-citations-by-appearance-using-bibtex) help?

Comment: I understand if we do not use `.bib` file and explicitly write the references inside the tex file. it is not able to modify them by appearance order.

Comment: My another question is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075429/modifying-revtex-for-title-author-name-and-abstract`  could I ask you to help please